# synchronize tables across different services(projects)

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, aws-lambda, microservices

I need some suggestions about snyc data tables across services(projects)
I using AWS lambda.

Problem:

service_A has table_A,

every time make any update to table_A send a message to service_B to make same update to table_B which is the same as table_A

sometimes those messages are getting failure

so table_B now is not same as table_A.

one suggested solution is to make a scheduler job and query table_A and make publish it to table_B

Any another suggestion to handle such case?

Comment: https://microservices.io/patterns/data/transactional-outbox.html

Answer (score 1):

Systems are always failing. So I think what you need is a strategy to address the failure scenario. Here is my suggestion:

table_A update > Lambda X > SQS Queue > Lambda Y > Table_B

Here, Lambda X will only responsible for send the update to the SQS queue. Lambda Y will pick the message from queue and update table B. You need to have a retry policy in the queue in case of an error. If it fails after certain retries, you might want to send the message to a dead letter queue and decide on what to do next to the failed message.

** Most importantly this update must be idempotent, because with retry, it is possible the same message will be processed more than once.

Comment: that's exactly what is the scenario right now, in some cases as you mentioned failure happened.
what I need is to keep table_A and table_B sync all the times